# How to build a filter for a stream builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I need to build a filter for a streambuilder. not sure where to start because the function was written by someone else and its kinda weird.

here is the function that grabs all the jobs:

```
 Stream<Iterable<CloudJob>> getAllOpenJobs() =>
      job.snapshots().map((event) => event.docs
          .map((doc) => CloudJob.fromSnapshot(doc))
          .where((job) => job.jobState == jobStateOpen));
```

I build a similar function, but it looks nothing like that. here is the one I build AND it works:

```
  getChatMessages({required chatMessageId}) {
    chatMessages
        .where(chatMessageIdColumn, isEqualTo: chatMessageId)
        .orderBy(
          chatMessageCreatedAtColumn,
          descending: true,
        )
        .snapshots();
  }
```

I need to re-write getAllOpenJobs to get jobs and order them from created date and job type.
the name of the job type on firebase is : jobTypeColumn
the name of the created date on firebase is : jobCreatedDateColumn:

the getAllJobs function is being called from from the following snip:

```
       ... MORE CODE HERE
    body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _jobsService.getAllOpenJobs(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
            case ConnectionState.active:
       ... MORE CODE HERE
```

not sure what to do .... I started making the new function, it looks like this:

```
 Stream<Iterable<CloudJob>> getAllOpenJobs(jobTypeQueu) =>
      job.snapshots().map((event) => event.docs
          .map((doc) => CloudJob.fromSnapshot(doc))
          .where((job) => job.jobType == jobTypeQueu));
```

is this the right approach?
How can I add the orderBy functionality?

Comment: Like in the first function, after retrieving all the jobs from firebase, it works as follow: take out all the data from the snapshot, then convert that data from JSON to CloudJob data type, and then filter out the resulting list where the CloudJob has the the job state of JobStateOpen

Comment: Can you post the structure of CloudJob class?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Stream<Iterable<CloudJob>> getAllOpenJobs(jobTypeQueu) =>
      job.snapshots().map((event) => event.docs
          .map((doc) => CloudJob.fromSnapshot(doc))
          .where((job) => job.jobType == jobTypeQueu)  );
                                                     ^
```

insert there .toList()..sorted((a,b) => ...your comparison))

e.g.

```
    Stream<Iterable<CloudJob>> getAllOpenJobs(jobTypeQueu) =>
    job.snapshots().map((event) => event.docs
        .map((doc) => CloudJob.fromSnapshot(doc))
        .where((job) => job.jobType == jobTypeQueu)
        .toList()
      ..sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b)));
```

This is not the most efficient approach but it is easy to read and maintain and should suffice if you're not dealing with huge amounts of data.

edit: replace ..sorted with ..sort

Comment: im dealing with a lot of data, :( . but thank you

Comment: What is a lot to you? This solution should work unless you are streaming thousands of CloudJobs per second. In this case, you should probably perform sorting on the backend.

Comment: I will try the sorting on the back end. but i do get an error with the snip you provided.

The method 'sorted' isn't defined for the type 'List'

Comment: My bad, it's sort not sorted.